# Stored procedure to check if less then one date entrance per week

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure. The input is going to be a date and ID and the procedure is going to set a value to true if there are 4 weeks with less then 2 inputs per week.

In my data only the weeks with the stars have less than two inputs and if I pass the date `7-7-2015` is going to set the output value to true

Any help will be appreciated. Do I need to iterate through every record and set a counter if less then two inputs or there is an easier way ?

```
ID      Date

1       7-7-2015    
2       6-23-2015
3       6-12-2015
1       7-8-2015
1       7-14-2015    *
1       7-21-2015    *
1       7-27-2015
1       7-28-2015
1       7-29-2015
1       7-30-2015
1       8-3-2015     *
1       8-11-2015    *
```

Comment: What would be the output from the proc? And in which date interval do you want the check to be done?

Comment: true if four weeks, false if less

Comment: Four weeks from the input date parameter until...? all records after that date, or a month or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways, but one way that should work is to use a windowed aggregate function (count) in a derived table, and then sum up the number of rows with count 1 and return true if the sum is >= 4. Something like this:

```
create proc sp_test (@id int, @d date)
as 
select case when sum(c) >= 4 then 'true' else 'false' end status
from (
    select c = count(*) over (partition by id, datepart(week, date))
    from t -- this is your table 
    where id = @id and date >= @d
) a
where c = 1
go
```

Execute it using:

```
exec sp_test @id = 1, @d = '2015-07-07'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The procedure doesn't work correctly in the following scenario.

Comment: The procedure has to work in the following scenario as well:  week Jul 13 - no records
week Jul 20 - no records
week Jul 27 - 2 records
Week Aug 3  - no records
Week Aug 10  - 2 records
Week Aug 17 - no records .   IF I pass date July 13

Comment: @LioLou There is no data for week Aug 17 in your sample data, so why would it be included? If you insert a record for that week then it returns true.

Comment: I need to check for the first four weeks with less than two records or zero records.

Comment: I am stack. Any Help?

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you want to do. This procedure will check if there are four weeks with less than 2 records in the time period from the starting date until the end. You need to clarify what it should do and I'm sure I can fix it (once I understand).