# Stored Procedure to check if four weeks with less then two records

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a stored procedure. The input is going to be a date and ID and the procedure is going to set a value to true if there are 4 weeks with less then 2 inputs per week.
It has to take in consideration that I might pass an early date with no records in the database.
I couldn't format the code. I don't know why?
So far I got that with previous help from you guys:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[sp_test] (@id int, @d date)
as 
declare @WeekFirstRecord as int
declare @WeeksWithNoRecords as int
SET @WeekFirstRecord = datepart(week,(select Min(ZeroPointIncidentDate) from EmployeeZeroPointIncidents where ZeroPointIncidentDate > @d))
SET @WeeksWithNoRecords = datepart(week, @WeekFirstRecord)  - datepart(week, @d)  
select case when sum(c) + @WeeksWithNoRecords   >= 4 then 'true' else 'false' end status
from (
    select c = count(*) over (partition by EmpId, datepart(week, ZeroPointIncidentDate))
    from EmployeeZeroPointIncidents 
     where EmpId = @id and ZeroPointIncidentDate >= @d 
) a
where c = 1
```

In my data only the weeks with the stars have less than two inputs and if I pass the date `7-7-2015` is going to set the output value to true

Any help will be appreciated. Do I need to iterate through every record and set a counter if less then two inputs or there is an easier way ?

```
ID      Date

1       7-7-2015    
2       6-23-2015
3       6-12-2015
1       7-8-2015
1       7-14-2015    *
1       7-21-2015    *
1       7-27-2015
1       7-28-2015
1       7-29-2015
1       7-30-2015
1       8-3-2015     *
1       8-11-2015    *
```

If I had week Jul 13 - no records week Jul 20 - no records week Jul 27 - 2 records Week Aug 3 - no records Week Aug 10 - 2 records Week Aug 17 - no records And pass Jul 12 date should return true, if I pass jul 15 should return false

Comment: When you say `if there are 4 weeks with less then 2 inputs per week` it doesn't make any sense at all, what are these parameters that you pass to the stored procedure will have to do the four weeks? how do you calculate these 4 weeks from the date you pass? can you show some sample data and desired output also give explanation about the desired output you show.

Comment: I believe that I accepted the answer. I haven't use much stack overflow and if I made any mistake I am sorry                                                         I If I had  week Jul 13 - no records
week Jul 20 - no records
week Jul 27 - 2 records
Week Aug 3  - no records
Week Aug 10  - 2 records
Week Aug 17 - no records                  And pass Jul 12 date should return true, if I pass jul 15  should return false

Comment: You asked this question before earlier on this morning [`Stored procedure to check if less then one date entrance per week`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130534/stored-procedure-to-check-if-less-then-one-date-entrance-per-week),  The sample data you have  does not make any sense, please provide a more human understandable sample data and explain the term you have used `if there are 4 weeks with less then 2 inputs per week`, if you fail to do so I will be voting to close this question as it is unclear what are you asking, thank you.

Comment: Do you understand my explanation from the comment. Basically I need to find out if there are at least 4 weeks with less then two records. The weeks could not be consecutive.

Comment: As @t-clausen.dk mentioned you haven't accepted any of the answers given to your previously asked question, Accepting an answer which helped you is indication if the solution would work for other users or not, the community is helping you to solve your problems and you should help the community by being active playing your part.

Comment: How do you accept answer. I thought that I just have to click over the upper arrow.

Answer (score 1):

I had to see your sample data set from your last question along with explanation from your last question as well as the explanation given in this question to come up with this solution.

When you ask a question here put yourself in the reader's shoes and see if the question makes any sense, anyway I hope this solution will get you what you want. cheers

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_output
  @Date   DATE 
 ,@ID     INT
 ,@Output INT OUTPUT  -- 1 true , 0  false
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Count INT;

SELECT  @Count = COUNT(*)
FROM    TableName
WHERE   CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @Date), 0) AS DATE) 
                        = CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [Date]), 0) AS DATE) 
 AND    ID = @ID 
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [Date]), 0) AS DATE) 

  IF (@Count < 2) 
    SET @Output = 1;
  ELSE 
    SET @Output = 0;  

END
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the proc doesn't do what I need. I need proc that count the weeks with less than 2 records(incidents in my case) and return false if less then 4 weeks. if I pass a date 6 weeks ago and we have first week no record, second week two records, third week no record, fourth week two records, five week no record and six week 1 record .   The return must be true

Comment: Hey guys I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated.